# Bootstrap make accordion collapse by clicking heading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make my accordion collapse after clicking the heading rather than just the text in the heading? Right now it only collapses when I click "Major".

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P63pp/

My accordion html:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordian" href="#collapseMajor">
                    Major
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseMajor" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="All" title="major" class="check-all-majors" checked>
                            All Majors
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="AFM" title="major" class="check-majors" checked>AFM
                        </label>
                    </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="ARTS" title="major" class="check-majors" checked>ARTS
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="CHEM" title="major" class="check-majors" checked>CHEM
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make the `a` tag a block element and apply the panel-heading padding the `a`. You could create a `panel-accordion` panel and use that for all accordion panels. [**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/P63pp/2/)

```
.panel-accordion .panel-heading
{
    padding: 0;
}

.panel-accordion .panel-heading a
{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

Comment: This also works in Bootstrap UI for AngularJS. I did not try the data-toggle method, but I guess this would not work in that case.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks dfsq! If you remove the  tag, the underline behavior goes away - works even better!

I also moved the other attributes up to the panel-heading div - away from the  tag that bootstrap sample code gives you. This makes the panel-heading act in the same way as the old  did...

```
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne" data-target="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
    <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsable Group Item #1</h4>
</div>
```

I added some CSS on the page to change the cursor:

```
    <style> .panel-heading { cursor: pointer; } </style>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change HTML a little:

```
<div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseMajor">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a href="#collapseMajor">Major</a>
    </h4>
</div>
```

So just add `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseMajor"` to `.panel-heading` div.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P63pp/1/